# Use TinyMCE on Custom Post Type without Content

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to setup a custom post type in WordPress that contains a textarea that I want to turn into a TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor. The second-to-last post on [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-verve-meta-boxes-tinymce-support-on-textarea) shows how to embed JavaScript that will call TinyMCE on the text editor. However, when I try to use it, I get a JavaScript error that `tinyMCE` is not defined.

It looks like the problem is that because the post type doesn't have content, the editor JavaScript (which includes the global `tinyMCE` object) isn't being included in the admin page. How do I include these scripts so that I can then access `tinyMCE`?

Thanks,

-Nate

Comment: yepp, tiny_mce.js needs to be loaded on that page

Comment: So what's the best way to do that through WordPress's hooks / actions? It's an admin page, so it's not as though I can simply include the JavaScript file, right?

Comment: that's true afaik, unfortunatly i do not know how to make that work in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [**`wp_editor`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor). See [other references](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_editor+is%3Aanswer) in WordPress Answers.

For testing, I had the CPT defined without an editor: `'supports' => array( 'title', 'comments' )`.

And used this Custom Meta Box:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_box_so_14611445' );

function add_custom_box_so_14611445() 
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'sectionid_so_14611445',
        __( 'Custom Editor' ),
        'inner_custom_box_so_14611445',
        'portfolio' 
    );
}

function inner_custom_box_so_14611445( $post ) 
{
    echo wp_editor( '', 'editor_id_so_14611445', array() );
}
```